# query fetch from sanity backend

Tags: javascript, sanity

I'm about to fetch data from Sanity backend by following a tutorial and i encountered this code below.

Kindly can you explain to me this part of code? specially `'*[_type == "abouts"]'`.
Thank you.

```
const About = () => {
  const [abouts, setAbouts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const query = '*[_type == "abouts"]';

    client.fetch(query).then((data) => setAbouts(data));
  }, []);
```

In Sanity backend, i created an `Abouts` content that can be acessed with URL: `http://localhost:3333/desk/abouts`.

Comment: It seme somthing like all records with type equal to about.

Comment: it's query, so it should be related to URL, no?

Comment: useEffect is somethin like data manager state in Reakt, i guest